# Delete function successful but returnin catch err message | Node .js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i have a destroy function

```
app.delete('/delete/items/:id', async(req, res) => {
  const id =  req.params.id;
  items.destroy({
    where:{
      id: id
    }
  }).then(res => {
    res.status(200).json("Items deleted")
  }).catch(err => {
    res.status(500).json("Can't delete Items")
  })
 })
```

the delete is working but it keeps returning the "Can't delete items"
[image: POSTMAN]

[image: Database]

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/): _StackOverflow is a question-and-answer site for specific questions about actual code; “I wrote some buggy code that I can’t fix” is not a question, it’s a story, and not even an interesting story._

Comment: Add `console.log(err)` to your `.catch()` and see what your error is.  This is BASIC troubleshooting/debugging which you should not be coming here for.

Comment: yess i come here because i dont know what to do, it's because i'm a novice in node js and sequelize so if i can't come here for asking a solution where would i be?

Comment: @jfriend00 to answer this question the error is, TypeError: res.status is not a function. i'm using res.status in my other function it's running well, why this happen only in destroy function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to answer this question the error is, TypeError: res.status is not a function. i'm using res.status in my other function it's running well, why this happen only in destroy function?

OK, that's because you're redefining the `res` variable with something else in  your `item.destroy(...).then(res => {... });`.  This `res` then replaces access to the `res` from the request (hiding it).  Change that second `res` to some other variable name:

```
app.delete('/delete/items/:id', (req, res) => {
  const id =  req.params.id;
  items.destroy({
    where:{
      id: id
    }
  }).then(data => {                            // changed res to data here
    res.json("Items deleted");
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);                          // always log error
    res.status(500).json("Can't delete Items");
  })
 })
```

Another morale to the story here is to ALWAYS log your errors on the server so you don't get confused about what's going on when it hits an error path.

FYI, `.status(200)` is unnecessary as 200 is already the default status.  So, you can also change `res.status(200).json(...);` to `res.json(...);`.

Answer (score 0):

change it into
idk but how can Sequelize using a lowerCase ?
but nvm

```
app.delete("/delete/items/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const find = await items.findByPk(id);
    if (!find) throw new Error("Data Not Found");
    const deleted = await items.destroy({ where: { id } });
    res.status(200).json({ message: `Deleted item with ID : ${deleted.id}` });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error);
  }
});
```

for the status it wasnt might be 500 ig, it used to be 401 400 because of u cannot to access the action but also can access the db

Comment: its because your code is still working, and ure not even catch any error from your code until the program run out and cannot working anymore so the program would be going into the catch promises, so the solution is u need to find the data first and use one of those method, promise/ async,await.

Comment: i know it, it just to handle if theres no such data with an id that i got from params, if theres no items with a same id from params so i throw an err, its just how i do, but if u were had a different way then tell it.